# Rounded Div Briefly Showing as Square on Initial Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used

```
// make main container visible
$( window ).load(function() {
  $( "#video-container" ).css( "visibility", "visible" );
});
```

but no luck. I figured the css would have already been applied to the div on load, but maybe I'm missing something.

CSS is as follows:

```
#video-container {
  background-color: #191919;
  border: 3px solid #999;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -13%;
  margin-top: -13%;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 26%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Rounded div? Where is the border-radius and how is it applied?

Comment: `$( window ).load()` completes the functions when everything else in the DOM has loaded. see the [**docs**](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Comment: Is your CSS in a separate file? Or in the `<header>` of the HTML file? It's entirely possible for the CSS file to be delayed in loading from the server. A simple workaround would be to duplicate "critical" portions of your CSS in the HTML header, but that could become a maintenance nightmare, depending on your environment. You might see if it's possible to attach an handler to loading of the CSS file, then set the visibility there. The right answer depends on your usability and experience requirements.

Comment: @Paulie_D: you just solved my problem, thanks! Border-radius was set in a function elsewhere, so I needed to invoke it on load. Simple problem, simple solution. I'll try to reorganize my code a bit to make this more clear. Thanks for the help. Feel free to make an official response, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `border-radius` declaration in your CSS so it's likely that this is set somehwere else,

I suggest that you check your other CSs/JS/JQ functions to ensure that this is added at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this... 
$( "#video-container" ).show();